# PHP - echo $row produces same output

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue where the output of the statement below shows the correct content, but when I click one of the items (a hyperlink) they all end up at the same page with the same name of the bottom row:

```
<table class="center">
    <!-- Creating a table with the class of 'center' -->
    <!-- SEARCH FORM -->
    <?php
    $KEYWORD = $_POST['keyword'];
    $stmt    = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT dog_park_name FROM dog_parks.items WHERE dog_park_name LIKE '%{$KEYWORD}%'");
    $stmt->execute();
    for ($i = 0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); ++$i) {
        $_SESSION["dog_park"] = "$row[0]";
    ?>
        <!-- DISPLAY RESULTS -->
        <tr> <!-- Adding the first table row -->
            <th>Dog Park</th> <!-- Adding the second table header -->
        </tr>

        <tr> <!-- Adding the second table row -->
            <td><a href="individual_item_page.php" ><?php echo $row[0]; ?></a></td> <!-- Add the second cell on the second row -->
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

I search a keyword and it produces the following output which is correct:

```
TRAMWAY ST DOG OFF LEASH AREA  
STRINGYBARK DVE DOG OFF LEASH AREA
```

The problem comes in when I click on any of the results returned they all end up at the same page with the same name of the bottom row..

```
STRINGYBARK DVE DOG OFF LEASH AREA  
STRINGYBARK DVE DOG OFF LEASH AREA
```

I think it was something to do with the `$stmt->fetch()`

can't post pictures sorry...

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: You keep overwriting `$_SESSION['dog_park']` until only the last row is left. How do you expect this to work? You should have a link like `individual_item_page.php?park=blahblah`

Comment: Have updated it now, sorry never posted before.

Comment: Show `var_dump($row);` please.

Comment: Why don't you use `fetch_all` and iterate through that with foreach?

Comment: Replace the `session = $row` with your table row and you'll be fine

Comment: Use prepared statements to prevent sql injection;

Comment: change <?php echo $row[0]; ?> to <?php echo $row[$i]; ?>. Also, what is the use of this file individual_item_page.php? I hope you need to pass query string with this file and process. eg : <td><a href="individual_item_page.php?queryString=<?php echo $row[$i]; ?>" ><?php echo $row[$i]; ?></a></td>

Comment: @asurbernardo     VAR_DUMP($row);    

array(2) { ["dog_park_name"]=> string(29) "TRAMWAY ST DOG OFF LEASH AREA" [0]=> string(29) "TRAMWAY ST DOG OFF LEASH AREA" } array(2) { ["dog_park_name"]=> string(34) "STRINGYBARK DVE DOG OFF LEASH AREA" [0]=> string(34) "STRINGYBARK DVE DOG OFF LEASH AREA" }

Comment: You say you are 'clicking'? Output the $KEYWORD and see if it has value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Note: the change is here --> $row[0]  not  "$row[0]"
```

before `$_SESSION["dog_park"] = "$row[0]";`

after `$_SESSION["dog_park".$i] = $row[0];`

then get session value by

```
 $_SESSION["dog_park0"]; 
    $_SESSION["dog_park1"]; 
     $_SESSION["dog_park2"]; 
     $_SESSION["dog_park3"];
```

etc.,

Comment: Hi mate,
thanks for the comment,
have changed my code, 
it seems to still only one park to matter what keyword i search..

Comment: $KEYWORD = $_GET['keyword']; and  <a href="individual_item_page.php?keyword=<?php echo $row[0] ?>" >

Comment: Is this wrk for u?

Comment: Hi,
Does not seem to work,
Displays tables with no data 
screenshot below
[link](https://gyazo.com/24e8c423ec9e9d575445dc7ef761a695.png)

Comment: UPDATE WITH PICTURES:
When I search a keyword I get the correct results show in table,   
link below:  
[Table1](https://gyazo.com/04dc46ee4a659cd82cd61fbdbcedaf0d.png)  

If i click on the first result (TRAMWAY..), it will display the name of the   bottom result (STRINGBARK...) bottom result.  
[Result](https://gyazo.com/2dd44e2075232192652e130b07fe2183.png)
  
The code the page which displays this name is linked below:  
[individual_item_page.php]  (https://gyazo.com/f572bc3362c20b1fbcaee51e88ca1789.png)

Comment: still have doubt post the individual_item_page.php file fully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111751/discussion-between-deluxenathan-and-arun-g).

Answer (score -1):

If you want the loop to work correctly then you need to assign your data to a variable that won't be overridden, use i in both the session and row to increment otherwise use a foreach loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); ++$i) {
    $_SESSION["dog_park"][$i] = $row[$i];
?>
```

This would stop the session array from returning the same values. This way you are going over each result and setting it one by one (rather than setting everything to one value).

Comment: UPDATE WITH PICTURES:
When I search a keyword I get the correct results show in table,   
link below:  
[Table1](https://gyazo.com/04dc46ee4a659cd82cd61fbdbcedaf0d.png)  

If i click on the first result (TRAMWAY..), it will display the name of the   bottom result (STRINGBARK...) bottom result.  
[Result](https://gyazo.com/2dd44e2075232192652e130b07fe2183.png)
  
The code the page which displays this name is linked below:  
[individual_item_page.php]  (https://gyazo.com/f572bc3362c20b1fbcaee51e88ca1789.png)